# How to send a message through Youtube API manually?

Tags: javascript, variables, youtube-api, message

Ok this is what I want to do, I want to send a message through Youtube manually, using javascript. I am trying to find the very last line of code that sends a message in the Youtube API and then be able to execute that myself.

I do not want to just type

```
inbox.sendMessage();
```

into the JavaScript console.

Here is what I currently know:

The external js file that handles the messages:
http://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-inbox-vflCOzV-o.js

The function that starts sending the message is

```
inbox.sendMessage();
```

When this is called a function applied to the variable m.va is called.
This function has 2 important parts:
The parts that gather the message input values:

```
var b=H("compose_message").value;
```

(H is a function that is basically equivalent to document.getElementById)

and the second important part is when the function sends of the compiled information:

```
W(this,a,"send_message",h)
```

The above function compiles the information in a (the subject, message, attachments, to etc.) and sends them off by .push - ing the information onto an array referenced as this.s.t (this.s.t.push(f) is called, f being the compiled information).

Here is how the information is arranged in a from the function call above:

```
a.o = H("user_ext_ids").value;
a.p = H("compose_to").value;
a.V = this.a; (global variable unknown to me)
a.U = H("field_reference_video").value;
a.k = H("compose_subject").value;
a.e = H("compose_message").value;
```

Function W compiles the above into a new variable: f like so:

```
f.to_user_external_ids = H("user_ext_ids").value;
f.to_users = H("compose_to").value;
f.in_reply_to = this.a; (global variable unknown to me)
f.video_id = H("field_reference_video").value;
f.subject = H("compose_subject").value;
f.message_text = H("compose_message").value;
```

Once function W has compiled the information to f as above, it pushes it onto the end of an array, which I assume to be some sort of action queue, or a packet of information to be sent off along with other actions.

This is the code pushing the information:

```
a.t.push({type:c,request:f});
```

These are the references for the above line of code:

```
a = this.s; (Originally equalled this, when W was called by the first function, but is was changed to this at the beginning of W)
c = "send_message"; (I am guessing this is the part telling the script that the action is sending the message)
f - this is the compiled information that I mapped out above.
```

I managed to get as far as finding what this.s.t is being set to, but I am stuck beyond that.

```
this.s=new pb(a);
```

The variable s is set to this function. The function pb(a) can be found by Ctrl-F'ing:

```
function pb(a)
```

as with most of the functions and variable I have referenced here.

Inside the scope of pb(a), the variable this.t is initialized:

```
this.t=[];
```

I also found that within the same function that this.s=new pb(a); occurs, this.s is involved with another function and it is the only other time "this.s" (small s, not capital) is referenced in the whole script, other than a=a.s; Here is the function it is referenced in:

```
var c=R(R(R(R(R(R(R(R(R(R(this.s,"accept_message",this.v,this),"accept_messages",this.v,this),"block_user",this.v,this),"delete_message",this.v,this),"delete_messages",this.v,this),"display_messages",this.W,this),"ignore_message",this.v,this),"ignore_messages",this.v,this),"mark_as_spam",this.v,this),"send_message",this.Y,this);
```

This is as far as I could get, now I am completely stumped. Any help will be greatly appreciated, and I need to be able to get to the very last line of code where the message is actually sent, and nothing else is referenced, so I can manually send a message, with JavaScript independent from this script.

---

**Question:** Can you help me find the last line of code where a message is sent so I can manually send a message, with JavaScript independent from this js script.

Comment: Yes... looks like a very laid out question.... **BUT** I do not see the question!

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a question about reverse-engineering the JavaScript code used by the YouTube web interface to use it for a purpose it was not intended.

There is a supported way to send messages programmatically using the YouTube Data API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_messages

Please don't attempt to send messages using an unofficial mechanism. It's probably not possible, and if it is possible, it will probably break unexpectedly at some point in the future.